# Dojo tutorial - Business Application Architecture

Tags: javascript, frameworks, dojo

I want to write a full blown business application in JavaScript and have evaluated ExtJS intensivly. Now I want to take a closer look at Dojo. I found the tutorials at

[Dojo Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/)

but they seem to hightlight only single specific points each. What I am searching for is a tutorial that describes how to organise and architect a full application so that I can see its architectural differences compared with ExtJS.

Any suggestions where to look at first?

Thanks in advance!

Heinob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you read already these tutorials from the Dojo Documentation?

- [Using Dojo Behaviour](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/using_behavior/)
- [Aplication controller](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/recipes/app_controller)
- [Data Modeling for MVC Applications](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/data_modeling/)